# How to declare multiple module in different files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, declare

So I have a problem when importing a class that says `Cannot find module 'Cannot find module 'starnime/discord/webhook' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)` even if I did declare it on the typings folder.

I also tried to add `tsconfig.json` to my project, but it didn't work.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowUnreachableCode": false,
        "allowUnusedLabels": false,
        "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "noImplicitOverride": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "strict": true,
        "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,
        "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "allowJs": true,
        "target": "es2017",
        "noImplicitAny": true
    },
    "include": [
        "./**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

I'm expecting that when I try to import a class, it will be like this:

```
const { DiscordEmbed, DiscordWebhook } = require('starnime/discord/webhook');

// rest of the code
```

If you wish to help me out, you can check out the full code on Github: https://github.com/Stawa/Starnime.

Comment: Your require syntax is wrong. You are trying to require a file in `Starnime/node_modules/starnime/discord/webhook` - I'm fairly sure you don't have that file/folder in your `node_modules` folder because you don't have the module `starnime` as a dependency in your `package.json` file. If you want to import `webhook.js` you need to `require('./discord/webhook')` or `require('./lib/discord/webhook')`. You need to find the path correctly from the point of view of the file importing the module.

Comment: I'm not sure about your answer, but I did install Starnime and put it in `package.json`, `"starnime": "github:Stawa/Starnime"`. If I import from the source or lib folder, it works fine, but it's not being typed by the `d.ts` file. @slebetman